# igraph error cannot create empty graph with negative number of vertices

Tags: r, igraph

Why do I get an error when I try to create below simple graph? If i replace "a" and "b" with numbers then it works? any solution

```
g1 <- graph(c("a","b"),directed=TRUE)
```

error is

```
Error in graph(c("a", "b"), directed = TRUE) : 
  At type_indexededgelist.c:117 : cannot create empty graph with negative number of vertices, Invalid value
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In graph(c("a", "b"), directed = TRUE) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In graph(c("a", "b"), directed = TRUE) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Answer (score 5):

From `?graph`, you can read:

```
edges: Numeric vector defining the edges, the first edge points from the first element to the second, the second edge from the third to the fourth, etc.
```

Since it's looking for a numeric vector but you've given it text, it's converting all the letters to `NA` (this is the "NAs introduced by coercion."

You could convert the text to appropriate numeric identifiers with something like:

```
g1 <- graph(as.numeric(factor(c("a","b"))), directed=TRUE)
```