# tbl_graph function failed

Tags: r, networkx, igraph, tidygraph

I applied igraph to visualizing a network on a discussion forum.

```
rt_net <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes, edges = edges, directed = TRUE)
Error in (function (edges, n = max(edges), directed = TRUE)  : 
  At type_indexededgelist.c:117 : cannot create empty graph with negative number of vertices, Invalid value
```

When I checked back the matric of edgelist, there is no negative numbers. I also fill in missing value with 0

Comment: Can you show us what `nodes` is and what `edges` is?  Or at least the first few values?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819258/igraph-error-cannot-create-empty-graph-with-negative-number-of-vertices

Comment: Hi Joel -- Thanks for the response. Here is the head (nodes) head(nodes)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  handle out_degree in_degree
   <dbl>      <dbl>     <int>
1      1         18        24
2      2          5         1
3      3         44         1

Comment: I suspect it may be due the process of nodes creation as I got an error " Can't join on 'handle' x 'handle' because of incompatible types (factor / integer)"  so I transformed the handle like temp_in$handle = as.numeric(temp_in$handle). But for edge creation, no such problem. Could you help me figure it out? Thanks so much.

Comment: Hi Joel -- I solved the problem! Changed the node format to character. Thanks!